# I am using docker-compose.yml to generate a docker container and initial schemas. Everything loads fine, but the initial table is nowhere to be found

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I am trying to use an sh script to create a docker container with preloaded initial schemas. This means that I have a python main.py file that runs a bash script with the following code:

```
rm -rf postgres_data
docker-compose down --rmi all --volumes
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

And a docker-compose.yml with the following code:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.1
    container_name: mydatabasename_database
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "postgres", "-U", "root" ]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=MYDATABASENAME_DB
      - APP_DB_USER=appuser
      - APP_DB_PASS=appass
      - APP_DB_NAME=appname
    volumes:
      - ./init-schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db-01.sql
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I also have an sql script called init-schema.sql with the following code:

```
CREATE USER appuser WITH PASSWORD 'appass';
CREATE DATABASE mydatabasename_db;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydatabasename_db TO appuser;

\c mydatabasename_db;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
    client_id character varying(36) NOT NULL,
    value character varying(255)
);
```

Again, in the docker logs everything seems to be running as it should; however, when I try to connect to the container via dbeaver or pycharm, the table is non existent. All of these files are in the same directory by the way.

I have literally tried everything for the life of me. Initially, I tried simply using the `docker build` command and a Dockerfile to copy initial-schema.sql into the container directory via `COPY ./initial-schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/config.sql`, but this also did not work for some reason. Because of that, I instead moved to using the docker-compose plugin where I then wrote the code I provided above. I have no idea what else to do. I have also run the sql script manually and it works perfect. The table pops up in dbeaver and pycharm. I want everything to be loaded in a single step and this single error is what is left for me to accomplish that. I want to give you all thanks in advance! Hopefully, you guys can spot something that I am missing because I am completely out of ideas.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database to see what gets created?  To verify, you're seeing in the database container startup messages that `init-db-01.sql` is in fact getting run?  (You may find it more reliable to run `CREATE TABLE` commands like this via your application framework's migration system: this won't be tied to Docker, and you won't have to delete all of your existing data if you add more tables or otherwise change the database schema.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I use the Docker desktop client to see the container's logs when it is created and it is there that I can see that the initialization process does find and run the commands inside init-db-01.sql without producing any errors. However, when I connect to the database via DBeaver or Pycharm, although the container is present, no tables have been created. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself! It seems that naming the section `postgres` was causing problems. Changed my file to this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mydatabasename:
    image: postgres:13.1
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "postgres", "-U", "root" ]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./init-schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db-01.sql
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```